# Look up tables Ria Services

Tags: silverlight-4.0, ria, wcf-ria-services

My application has a master database which has around 50 tables which are used as lookup tables and will provide data to fill the comboboxes and any other controls and also some application settings tables. So I was thinking of creating these master tables context and load the entities and add it to the application life time context object upon user login so that I can access them throughout the application when ever I need. However I am also thinking of a different approach where I download the dataseset of all the tables and save it to the isolated storage and read the tables from that dataset when ever I need to load the combobox. The dataset with all the tables loaded is around the size 1.2MB. I do not know which one should I follow and what will be the shortcomings of these approaches when compared to each other and also is there an elegant way of handling such a case. Can anyone please suggest me ?

Thanks,
Ajay.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem you face with any solution is synchronization when any of these 50 tables change.  How would you even know if the change occurs outside the scope of both the server-side app and the Silverlight client?

I would simply opt to use output caching with RIA Services and put a reasonable cache expiration in place that ensures changes are incorporated on a somewhat reasonable interval.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/digital_ruminations/archive/2011/01/05/ria-services-output-caching.aspx

Comment: Actually these tables are supposed not to change and they may change very rarely only if there are any new requirements added to the application. I have looked into the link you have given and I was thinking how is that going to make any difference when compared to loading all the results into the object context.

Comment: Also if i use the isolated storage to download the dataset as xml is there a way to invalidate the dataset if there are any changes in the database just like automatic database server cache invalidation in asp.net

Comment: I agree, but keep in mind you cannot force users to allow more isolated storage than the default 1MB so account for that in your logic.